# React- onClick styling of currentTarget

Tags: reactjs, onclick, styles

I am trying to build a simple dynamically updated, interactive list that styles each `<li></li>` according to the css rules of a .clicked class, when you click on them.

The app is composed of two components, a parent and a child and the code in question is the following (taken from the child):

```
handleClick(e) {


    document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).setAttribute("class","clicked");


}  

render() {

let ar = this.props.sentences;


let pro = ar.map((x,i)=>{ return (<li id={i} key={i} className={i%2==0 ? "white" : "grey"} 
onClick={this.handleClick}>{x}</li>); })

return (
    <div>

        <ul id="ul">{ pro }</ul>                

    </div>
```

What is happening here is basically that the parent is passing to the child a sentences prop (an array of sentences that will form the basis for the formation of a dynamic list).

The controversial part is me using DOM manipulation in the form of `document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).setAttribute("class","two");`
 in order to change the class of the dynamically created html from jsx.

**The code above works**, however it does not feel as best practice. The whole advantage in using react is to use virtual dom and optimize the way the DOM is updated.

My questions are the following:

**1) Am I right to feel this way? (that my solution is not best practice?)**

**2) (If so, ) How can I structure my code in order to use the virtual dom machinery react offers?**

If you know this question to be a duplicate, please leave a comment and I ll remove it.

Comment: does the clicked `<li>` the only one that gets the `clicked` class

Comment: yes, that's the whole challenge.

Comment: correct but does it retain the clicked class even if more are clicked?

Comment: yes. I understand the first part of your answer (can you elaborate a bit more on why not use index of map as key? ) but the sec one I feel is a bit abstract: lets say I use state to collect all the elements that have been clicked so far inside a data structure like an array. Wont I have to use vanilla js at some point to actually change their class?

Comment: you shouldnt i dont think, can you post a sample `x` object from the map... I am curious what it looks like.  I am writing some code to add and I could use a few more details about `this.props.sentences` to further that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Am I right to feel this way? (that my solution is not best practice?)

It is correct to assume that this is not an ideal approach, manipulating the DOM via vanilla js in React has its place ([Example Use Cases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5e7kWSHWTg)) but should not be done unless absolutely necessary.  Also, it is not ideal to use the index from `Array.prototype.map` as the key on your components as if they change order it can cause confusion for React as the keys would map differently in that case.

> 2) (If so, ) How can I structure my code in order to use the virtual dom machinery react offers?

You should make use of the component state. If you want each clicked element to maintain the `clicked` class then make a piece of state that caches the elements that have already recieved the `clicked` class. if only the most recently clicked element gets the `clicked` class then simply cache an identifier to the appropriate element in the state. You could also use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for this purpose though the overusage of them is somewhat discouraged by facebook.

Here is a quick snipped that will toggle the `click` class on each `<li>`

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            clicked: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        let ar = this.props.sentences;

        let pro = ar.map((x, i) => {
            const color_class = i % 2 === 0 ? "white" : "grey";
            const clicked_class = this.state.clicked[i] === true ? "clicked" : "";

            let clicked = Object.assign({}, this.state.clicked); // Dont mutate state!!!

            return (
                <li
                    id={i}
                    key={i}
                    className={`${color_class} ${clicked_class}`}
                    onClick={e => {
                        if (clicked.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            delete clicked[i];
                        } else {
                            clicked[i] = true;
                        }
                        this.setState({ clicked });
                    }}
                >
                    {x}
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul id="ul">
                    {pro}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting our conv here for reference purposes. Well sentences can be anything, in its most basic form it would be ["a","b","c"]; that would generate a list of three li elements. I think you are spot on, that I should not use the index from map as keys. But what should I use if the props is constantly updated?

Comment: In general, using the index as the key from an `Array.prototype.map` call should not be done unless there is nothing guaranteed to be unique in the mapped over array (e.g. using a unique property of an object or if the values themsleves are unique then using the value is acceptable.

Comment: in this case, without knowing what `this.props.sentences` would be, I did elect to use the index as the key for each <li>

Comment: nice usage of template literals. I ll study the answer and possibilities further tonight. ty

Comment: no problem bro, feel free to hit that accept button ;).  Happy coding!

Comment: dude thanks. I am experimenting now with the multiple classes solution, which is very nice indeed, because it allows you to keep styles purely on the css side. That is a huge plus in my opinion. Nobody wants to mix structural js with styles am I right?

Comment: Inline styles are a thing that seem to be somewhat split among the react community.  I personally dont really like it as it isnt conducive to my particular workflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150883/discussion-between-alexandros84-and-canaan-seaton).